# How to transform any expression of the form $x^2 + ax + b$ into $y^2 + c$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I fee like this is a stupid question, but I am reading some first semester introductory material where the author goes over some common mistakes new students often make.

In this section of the text, the author displays the following:

$(a + b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$

He then claims it should be trivial to transform any expression of the form $x^2 + ax + b$ into the form $y^2 + c$, using the above identity. I'm not seeing it. Is it that apparent?

Comment: The idea is commonly called *completing the square*.

Comment: Thanks, I was indeed missing this concept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> $$
> x^2+ax+b
> = x^2+2x \cdot\frac{a}{2} + \left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^2 +b
> = \left(x-\frac{a}{2}\right)^2+\left(b-\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^2\right)
> \equiv y^2+c.
> $$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94218/discussion-between-soumalya-pramanik-and-ak19).

Answer (score 2):

We have
\begin{align*}
x^2 + ax + b
& =(x)^2 + 2 \cdot x \cdot \left(\frac{a}{2}\right) + \left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^2 + b - \left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^2 \\
& = \left(x + \frac{a}{2}\right)^2 + b - \frac{a^2}{4} \\
& = \left(x + \frac{a}{2}\right)^2 - \frac{4b - a^2}{4} \\
& = \left(x + \frac{a}{2}\right)^2 + c, \text{ where } c \text{ is } \left[- \frac{4b - a^2}{4}\right].
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$
x^2 + ax + b = (x + \frac{a}{2})^2 + b - \frac{a^2}{4}
$$

Answer (score 1):

What they are referring to is the technique of completing the square $$x^2+ax+b=x^2+ax+\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^2+b=\left(x+\frac{a}{2}\right)^2+\left(b-\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^2\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

$$x^2 + a x + b = x^2 + 2(a/2)x +(a/2)^2 -(a/2)^2 +b$$

Does that help?